# How to refer to a specific struct in an array, while the array is in a struct in a function in C?

Tags: c

the program is run: ./program objekty

objekty - name of file without .txt

Here is the problem which should be as minimal as possible:
(I'm trying to get both printfs on stdout)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct obj_t {
    int id;
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct cluster_t {
    int size;
    int capacity;
    struct obj_t *obj;
};
void obj_ctor(struct obj_t *p, struct obj_t obj){
    p->id = obj.id;
    p->x = obj.x;
    p->y = obj.y;
}
void pass(struct cluster_t *p, struct obj_t add){
    obj_ctor(&p->obj[0],add);
    p->size += 1;
}
void pass1(struct cluster_t **arr){
    struct obj_t o3;
    o3.id = 1; o3.x = 2; o3.y = 3;
    int count = 20;
    int pos = 0;
    while(pos < 3){
    arr[pos]->capacity = 3;
    arr[pos]->size = 0;
    arr[pos]->obj = malloc(count*sizeof(struct obj_t));
    pass(arr[pos], o3);
    pos++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Testing");
    struct cluster_t *test;
    pass1(&test);
    printf("GOT HERE");
}
```

Comment: Instead of describing what your code does, [edit] your question with a [mcve].

Comment: The step in `main()` appears to create an uninitialized pointer to a `cluster_t`.  That isn't an array unless you are not showing us something crucial.  Does the `load_clusters()` function allocate the array?  Show us the real code.  There are too many gaps in your description.

Comment: `arr[pos]` as described in your question would be an error, it should be `(*arr)[pos]`

Comment: @StephenNewell thanks for the advice, the question thread now contains a minimal example

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have added a pastebin link to the thread (https://pastebin.com/cffiDYBm)

Comment: Put the code in the question!  [mcve]

Comment: @JonathanLeffler okay, the code is there

Comment: The requirement is "Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example" (MCVE) or "Minimal, Reproducible Example" (MRE) or "Short, Self-Contained, Complete Example" ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)).  I'm not convinced that the code you've added is minimal.   Yes, it takes effort to produce minimal code.  But it also gets you results without annoying those who might be willing to help you.  ___[…Time Passeth…]___ Maybe there is a minimal version there — but we really only want to see the minimal version.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well, the minimal example should be on the bottom of the question, I have made a new program with the same structs and it never gets to the "GOT HERE" log. Right beneath the "Here is the same problem that should be as minimal as possible:" line.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm sorry for the unused structs, I need to edit my minimal code some more, gimme a second

Comment: When I compile one version of your code, I get told that `o1` and `o2` are set but not used.  At no point do you set `test.obj`, but you try to use it in `pass()`, which therefore fails.  You need something like `struct obj_t arr[] = { o1, o2, o3 };` and `test.obj = arr;`.  Then you might be in with a fighting chance.  You should always end diagnostic messages with a newline — otherwise, you're likely not to see the messages in a timely manner.  You must give the `obj` member space to hold data.  You probably have issues with `struct obj_t` vs `struct obj_t *`.  You don't check the capacity.

Comment: But I agree — you have got the code at the end nicely minimal.  Should you be dynamically allocating the array of objects?  Or should you be dynamically allocating an array of object pointers and dynamically allocating a new object each time you use the constructor?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler To be honest, I don't know how to answer that, I edited the minimal code so it would better fit the case that I'm currently in, maybe that will help answer your question

Comment: Your main code is using dynamic memory — `malloc()` and `realloc()`.  Your `init_cluster()` function in the main code does set `c->obj = NULL;`.  You do have a `print_cluster()` function analogous to the `dump_cluster()`.  But that code also has a lot of extraneous material in it — sorting functions, merging, clearing, distances, etc.  Those should not be shown — they aren't relevant to your immediate problem of adding entries to clusters.  We should not have to wade through the irrelevant to find the relevant.  The comments aren't helpful to those who don't speak Czech.  Ideally, they'd go.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the original program is stripped of unnecessary parts

Comment: That is very much what would have been helpful from the start — and I'd count that as close enough to minimal not to need the even more minimal version.  Some sample input data would be helpful, but that's a refinement.  Please read the [MCVE] link — it covers a lot of this ground.  I know you're new to SO; that's why I'm helping you to get a feel for how you can ask questions that can be easily answered by those who would help you.  At least, that's what I'm trying to do.  Many people are less patient with newcomers than I am.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for being patient, I'll add an input file with the correct structure so you could reproduce everything.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've updated the information and it seems like that the behavior rapidly changes when I try to make the minimal code more similar to the original. I believe that if someone can fix this minimal version it would be 100% applicable to the real one. Again, I'm sorry for all the confusion, this is my first question on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final minimal example is nicely manageable — thank you.  Here is a fairly straight-forward extension of that code.  It is lazy in that it uses `assert()` to enforce necessary properties.

It includes a function to dump the data in a `struct cluster_t` structure.  I regard such functions as a necessity — at the very least, they're extremely helpful.  Quite often, I write them to take a `FILE *fp` argument so that messages can be written to standard output, standard error or to a log file, or, indeed, anywhere you can point a file stream.  Often, I'd have a separate `dump_obj()` function that would be invoked from `dump_cluster()`, but it doesn't seem necessary here.

The key point is that it ensures that `test.obj` in `main()` points to an array of 3 `struct obj_t`.  If you want dynamic memory allocation, changes are needed.

```c
/* SO 7467-2430 */
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct obj_t
{
    int id;
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct cluster_t
{
    int size;
    int capacity;
    struct obj_t *obj;
};

static void obj_ctor(struct obj_t *p, struct obj_t obj)
{
    p->id = obj.id;
    p->x = obj.x;
    p->y = obj.y;
}

static void pass(struct cluster_t *p, struct obj_t add)
{
    assert(p != NULL && p->obj != NULL);
    assert(p->size < p->capacity);
    obj_ctor(&p->obj[p->size], add);
    p->size += 1;
}

static void dump_cluster(const char *tag, struct cluster_t *p)
{
    printf("%s (%p):\n", tag, p);
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("size = %d, capacity = %d, objects = %p\n", p->size, p->capacity, p->obj);
        for (int i = 0; i < p->size; i++)
            printf("  [%d] id = %d, pos = (%g, %g)\n", i, p->obj[i].id, p->obj[i].x, p->obj[i].y);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Testing\n");
    struct cluster_t test;
    struct obj_t o1, o2, o3;
    o1.id = 1;
    o2.id = 2;
    o3.id = 3;
    o1.x = 1;
    o2.x = 2;
    o3.x = 3;
    o1.y = 1;
    o2.y = 2;
    o3.y = 3;
    test.capacity = 3;
    test.size = 0;
    struct obj_t arr[3]; 
    test.obj = arr;

    pass(&test, o3);
    printf("GOT HERE\n");
    dump_cluster("After adding 1", &test);
    pass(&test, o2);
    pass(&test, o1);
    dump_cluster("After adding 3", &test);

    return 0;
}
```

Example output (the addresses will probably differ for you):

```
Testing
GOT HERE
After adding 1 (0x7ffeed15b3b0):
size = 1, capacity = 3, objects = 0x7ffeed15b3c0
  [0] id = 3, pos = (3, 3)
After adding 3 (0x7ffeed15b3b0):
size = 3, capacity = 3, objects = 0x7ffeed15b3c0
  [0] id = 3, pos = (3, 3)
  [1] id = 2, pos = (2, 2)
  [2] id = 1, pos = (1, 1)
```

Comment: Really thank you for the effort, could this be reproduced if the cluster_t test was an array?

Comment: something like test[position]->obj = arr;? the "->" is there because im doing this in a function instead of main()

Comment: It could be extended to manage an array of `struct cluster_t` values, yes.  See also my latest [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74672430/how-to-refer-to-a-specific-struct-in-an-array-while-the-array-is-in-a-struct-in/74672750#comment131799684_74672430) after the question.  Not everyone has a program that removes C comments.  Doing that reliably is actually quite hard (`printf("/* This is not a comment! */\n");` doesn't contain a comment).  If you want such a program, I can send you SCC — Strip C Comments (which also handles C++, and handles C2x, aka C23); see my profile on SO.